# NullReferenceException while accessing LongListSelector Item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 App
and I did a LongListSelector for Players in the app

**LongListSelector**

```
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="playersLongList" LayoutMode="List" IsGroupingEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="653" Margin="15,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="412" SelectionChanged="playersLongList_SelectionChanged">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="s1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="playerName" Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Moire Light.ttf#Moire Light" FontSize="48" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Now, what i need is when the player taps on an item, the app shows a MessageBox that shows the Player Name of the Selected Item , and this is how i did it in the EventHandler

```
 private void playersLongList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var tb = sender as TextBlock;
     string fname = tb.Text;
     MessageBox.Show("hello"+fname);
 }
```

the debug shows `NullReferenceException` at `string fname = tb.Text;`

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Which class you use to bind `longlist`

Comment: Have you checked what the actual type of `sender` is in this case? Apparently it's not a `TextBlock`. It's probably a `LongListSelector`.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Player.cs (contains info fields) , it doesn't matter alot

Comment: Your `sender` is a `LongListSelector`. Grab that one first and then find the TextBlock in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
private void playersLongList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        Player p = e.AddedItems[0] as Player;
        string fname = p.FirstName;
        MessageBox.Show("hello"+fname);
    }
}
```